# Calculate Employee Salary Difference from salary structure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Given my employees:

[image]

I want each month difference HeadId wise like (salaryAmount(salarymonth(8))-salaryAmount(salarymonth(4)))*(8-4) and add each difference employee with HeadId wise like this

Desired Calculatioin & output:

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38GG3.jpg)

Comment: How is that 33000 calculated??

Comment: (41000-40000)*(12-8)=4000---------
(40000-35000)*(8-4)=20000------
(35000-26000)*(4-3)=9000--------
--------------------------4000+20000+9000=33000